# Group by id having max(date_field)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

To build a report, I must select some information on the last transaction status of all my customers. Until now, this is what I got:

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname, d.product_name, o.payment, s.name, h.date_add
FROM ps_orders o
INNER JOIN ps_order_detail d ON d.id_order = o.id_order
INNER JOIN ps_customer c ON c.id_customer = o.id_customer
INNER JOIN ps_order_history h ON o.id_order = h.id_order
INNER JOIN ps_order_state_lang s ON s.id_order_state = h.id_order_state
WHERE s.id_lang =6
GROUP BY c.id_customer
HAVING MAX(h.date_add)
```

For each customer, this query is selecting the first date (the field **h.date_add**) when I need of the last one. It seems the MySQL is ignoring the **HAVING**.

I tried to make a sub-select, but it doesn't work too.

Thanks any answer.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `HAVING MAX(...) something` like `>1` or some condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, you need to have a subquery which gets the latest `date_add` for every `id_order` on table `ps_order_history`. The result of the subquery is then joined back on the original table `ps_order_history` provided that it macth on two columns: `date_add` and `id_order`.

```
SELECT  c.firstname, 
        c.lastname, 
        d.product_name, 
        o.payment, 
        s.name, 
        h.date_add
FROM    ps_orders o
        INNER JOIN ps_order_detail d ON d.id_order = o.id_order
        INNER JOIN ps_customer c ON c.id_customer = o.id_customer
        INNER JOIN ps_order_history h ON o.id_order = h.id_order
        INNER JOIN  
        (
            SELECT  id_order, MAX(date_add) max_date
            FROM    ps_order_history
            GROUP   BY id_order
        ) x ON  h.id_order = x.id_order AND
                h.date_add = x.max_date
        INNER JOIN ps_order_state_lang s ON s.id_order_state = h.id_order_state
WHERE   s.id_lang =6
GROUP   BY c.id_customer
```

Comment: Thank you! It solved. Just a little correction:
...
    SELECT  id_order, MAX(h.date_add) max_date
    FROM    ps_order_history h
    GROUP   BY h.id_order

Answer (score 3):

To get the last date, you need to join it in:

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname, d.product_name, o.payment, s.name, h.date_add
FROM ps_orders o
INNER JOIN ps_order_detail d ON d.id_order = o.id_order
INNER JOIN ps_customer c ON c.id_customer = o.id_customer
INNER JOIN ps_order_history h ON o.id_order = h.id_order
INNER JOIN ps_order_state_lang s ON s.id_order_state = h.id_order_state
inner join (select o.id_customer, max(oh.date_add) as maxdate from ps_order_history h join ps_order o on h.id_order = o.id_order group by o.id_customer) omax on omax.id_customer = o.id_customer and o.date_add = omax.maxdate
WHERE s.id_lang =6
GROUP BY c.id_customer
```

Your having clause calculates the maximum date and then succeeds when it is not equal to 0 (which would be most of the time).

Comment: The table **ps_order_history** doesn't have the field **id_customer**. **ps_orders** has. I tried to fix this, but didn't work:
...
SELECT o.id_customer, max( h.date_add ) AS maxdate
FROM ps_order_history h
INNER JOIN ps_orders o ON o.id_order = h.id_order
...