# MySQL: select max date from table2 and group by ID from table1 where table2 date can be null

Tags: mysql, datetime, null, group-by, max

As the title of my question says, I tried for hours to figure out which MySQL query might return one result per each table1 ID (`GROUP BY ´ID´`) and, at the same time, select the maximum value of date in table2, taking into account that this date can be sometimes null.
I've tried with `LEFT JOIN`, with `HAVING`, with subqueries, but nothing seems to return a consistent result: the nearest query I've tested returns the max date in most cases but not in all of them.

**Query:**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(C.`ClauQuadern`)) AS files,C.`ID`,C.`Data`,C.`IDFactura`,C.`DataFactura`,C.`Cognoms` AS nom,SUM(C.`Grams`) AS pes_total,SUM(C.`Quantitat`) AS nq,C.`Client`,C.`Missatge`,C.`PerPreparar`,Q.`PerReservar`,Q.`DataImpressio`
FROM `Comandes` C
INNER JOIN `Quaderns` Q ON C.`ClauQuadern`=Q.`Clau`
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT `Clau`, MAX(`DataImpressio`) AS max_data 
    FROM `Quaderns` 
    GROUP BY `Clau`
) X ON Q.`Clau`=X.`Clau` AND Q.`DataImpressio`=X.max_data 
WHERE 
(
    (Q.`DataImpressio` IS NOT NULL AND C.`DataAnulacio` IS NULL AND 
        (
            (
                (C.`Modalitat`='T' OR C.`Modalitat`='TA' OR C.`Modalitat`='U' OR C.`Modalitat`='M') 
                AND C.`Gestio`<=1
            ) 
            OR 
            (
                (C.`Modalitat`='R' OR C.`Modalitat`='RA' OR C.`Modalitat`='D') 
                AND C.`Gestio`<=0
            )
        )
    ) 
    OR Q.`DataImpressio` IS NULL
) 
GROUP BY C.`ID`
ORDER BY C.`PerPreparar` DESC, Q.`DataImpressio` DESC, C.`ID` DESC
LIMIT 0, 25
```

**Table `Comandes`**

```
CREATE TABLE `Comandes` (
 `Clau` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Data` datetime NOT NULL,
 `IDFactura` int(11) default NULL,
 `DataFactura` datetime default NULL,
 `Client` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `ClauQuadern` int(5) NOT NULL,
 `Quantitat` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Grams` int(5) NOT NULL,
 `Modalitat` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
 `Gestio` smallint(2) NOT NULL default '-1',
 `DataAnulacio` datetime default NULL,
 `Cognoms` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `Missatge` text,
 `PerPreparar` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
 PRIMARY KEY  (`Clau`),
 KEY `Client` (`Client`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**Table `Quaderns`**

```
CREATE TABLE `Quaderns` (
 `Clau` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `PerReservar` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
 `DataImpressio` datetime default NULL,
 `Codi` char(6) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`Codi`),
 UNIQUE KEY `Clau` (`Clau`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**Other considerations:**

- In table `Comandes` there are multiple rows with same `ID`, each of them references one record from table `Quaderns`.
- `DataImpressio` from table `Quaderns` can be null.

**Output: (edited)**

```
files  ID    Data                         IDFactura DataFactura               Cognoms              pes_total  nq   Client  Missatge     PerPreparar  PerReservar  DataImpressio
4      3488  October, 20 2015 15:55:28    (null)    (null)                    De Mesa              1710       4    2226    (null)       true         false        (null) <- shouldn't be null!
3      3476  October, 15 2015 00:10:29    (null)    (null)                    REVERTER ROIG        970        3    1616    (null)       true         false        (null) <- shouldn't be null!
1      3480  October, 16 2015 10:44:00    (null)    (null)                    del valle garcia     310        1    534     (null)       false        false        October, 23 2015 00:00:00
3      3485  October, 18 2015 11:42:32    (null)    (null)                    Palmero              1225       3    919     (null)       false        false        (null) <- shouldn't be null!
1      3484  October, 17 2015 23:44:20    1715      October, 20 2015 14:25:51 Clausell García      250        2    2224    (null)       false        false        (null)
5      3483  October, 17 2015 11:45:33    1713      October, 18 2015 16:29:43 ( a la atención...   1540       5    334     (null)       false        false        (null) <- shouldn't be null!
1      3481  October, 17 2015 07:21:14    (null)    (null)                    Calm Codina          125        1    2223    (null)       false        false        (null)
1      3479  October, 15 2015 22:03:44    1712      October, 16 2015 12:59:26 Seoane Prieto        380        1    1853    He visto...  false        false        (null)
2      3478  October, 15 2015 20:11:36    (null)    (null)                    Serrano              525        2    858     (null)       false        false        (null) <- shouldn't be null!
1      3477  October, 15 2015 13:15:11    (null)    (null)                    Aguado Díaz          365        1    1530    (null)       false        false        (null) <- shouldn't be null!
2      3475  October, 14 2015 22:27:21    (null)    (null)                    lopez gil            335        2    2211    (null)       false        false        (null) <- shouldn't be null!
```

**Observations: (edited)**

- As `ORDER BY` clause says (`ORDER BY C.´PerPreparar´ DESC, Q.´DataImpressio´ DESC, C.´ID´ DESC`), the results are ordered first those that have a `true` as `PerPreparar` (first 2 results) and second those that have a `false` (last 9 results).
- In turn, these 2 and 9 results are sub-ordered by `´DataImpressio´ DESC` and sub-sub-ordered by `´ID´ DESC`.

**Conclusion: (edited)**

Everything would be alright, but it turns out that rows with `ID` 3488, 3476, 3480, 3485, 3483, 3478, 3477 and 3475 should have a non null value as `DataImpressio`. Something suggests that the `GROUP BY` clause from the main query is not considering the condition that `DataImpressio` should always be the max from the subset, before grouping by.

**Additional considerations: (added)**

*Records from table `Quaderns` that have non null values for `DataImpressio`:*

```
Quaderns.Codi:          A0044                G0013                P0001
Quaderns.Clau:          405                  406                  162
Quaderns.DataImpressio: 2015-10-19 00:00:00  2015-10-23 00:00:00  2015-10-22 00:00:00
```

*Simplified table of results:*

```
Comandes.ID   Comandes.ClauQuadern    Quaderns.DataImpressio
3488          contains 405            2015-10-19 00:00:00 (ERROR: outputs NULL instead)
3476          contains 405 & 406      2015-10-23 00:00:00 (ERROR: outputs NULL instead)
3480          contains 406            2015-10-23 00:00:00 (CORRECT: probably because for this Comandes.ID there is only 1 row)
3485          contains 405            2015-10-19 00:00:00 (ERROR: outputs NULL instead)
3483          contains 405            2015-10-19 00:00:00 (ERROR: outputs NULL instead)
3478          contains 406            2015-10-23 00:00:00 (ERROR: outputs NULL instead)
3477          contains 405            2015-10-19 00:00:00 (ERROR: outputs NULL instead)
3475          contains 162            2015-10-22 00:00:00 (ERROR: outputs NULL instead)
```

I noticed that changing the order of insertion in the table `Comandes`, if the row referenced to a not null `´Quaderns´.´DataImpressio´` is first inserted, then the query recognizes the non null value. Thus, this points out that the clause `GROUP BY` is only taking into consideration the first of the inserted rows for each `ID`, instead of getting the row in which `´Quaderns´.´DataImpressio´` is max.

I have already searched for similar questions in stackoverflow such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483739/mysql-subquery-select-in-join-clause) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764935/group-by-id-having-maxdate-field) but all approaches to the solution have ended up with the same result in my case. Either I am committing a tiny stupid error I can't see or my case needs some extra workaround.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** in order to help you help me, I created an [**SQLfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc5ac/1) where you can see the output (please, wait a couple of seconds until it loads).

Comment: Unfortunately you are misusing the (really confusing and nasty) custom MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. Read this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html  Your misuse of this extension makes it hard, both for MySQL and a human, to understand the intent of your query.